# How can I use radio buttons properly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing my first project using Ruby on Rails and need to display a set of radio buttons. It should behave exactly like a selection list. For usability reasons, I need it in a radio buttons format.

In my project, I use the collection select which also allows me to display on the edit page as follows:

```
select('project','project_type_id',@project_types.collect{|project_type|[project_type.name,project_type.id]}) <br>
```

I need something exactly like this, (especially the ability to display the selected value in the edit page) but using radio buttons.

I did a Google search and read the entire Rails guides on radio buttons but I can't find the answer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can do it like this in your view

```
<% @project_types.each do |project_type| %>
  <%= radio_button("project", "project_type", project_type.name) %> #assuming you have a name attribute on project_type
<% end %>
```

If you want a particular radio button to be checked then you can pass the checked option like so

```
<%= radio_button("project", "project_type", project_type.name, {:checked => true}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks
The loop is working well but if I put inside it the {: checked => true} it checks all the radio buttons and not just the selected value. I need a way in witch I can select just the user selected value, the same like the collect options does in the select list

Comment: Ok I try it again and now only with the loop and without the {: checked => true} option and it is working like magic.
When I am in the edit page rails seems to recognize the selected value and checks it according to the user selection

Comment: Yes, rails sticks the checked option depending upon the object. I mentioned that option in case you want to check some radio button explicitly.